# A dfifferent definition of continuity?

Tags: calculus, functions, continuity

Let $f:\Bbb R \to \Bbb R$ be a continuous function. Prove that for every $x \in \Bbb R$ and for every $A>0$ there is a $B>0$ such that for every $y \in \Bbb R$,  $\lvert y-x\rvert \le A
 \Rightarrow   \lvert f(x)-f(y)\rvert \le B $.

It looks a lot like just regular defenition of continuity, but A and B "switched places". Any help in writing a formal proof? Thanks.

Comment: I tried to use the regular definition, but I'm pretty stuck. Can't figure out how to swap them.

Comment: In other words, the assertion is that $f([x-A, x+A])$ is bounded.

Comment: Continuous on all $\mathbb R \implies$ continuous on $[x - A, x + A] \implies $ uniformly continuous on  $[x - A, x + A] \implies $ bounded on  $[x - A, x + A] \implies $ bounded on  $(x - A, x + A) $